# OpenSsl generate different signatures in Windows and Linux Platforms

Tags: openssl

Here is the command :
`echo -n "x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT" openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "abc" | openssl base64`

The result in windows: LW4gIngtZGF0ZTogV2VkLCAxMyBPY3QgMjAyMSAwOTozMDowMCBHTVQiIG9wZW5z
c2wgZGdzdCAtYmluYXJ5IC1zaGEyNTYgLWhtYWMgImFiYyIgDQo=

The result in Linux:  eC1kYXRlOiBXZWQsIDEzIE9jdCAyMDIxIDA5OjMwOjAwIEdNVCBvcGVuc3NsIGRn
c3QgLWJpbmFyeSAtc2hhMjU2IC1obWFjIGFiYw==

How do I do to generate the same result(Linux version) with windows command?

Thanks a lot.

---

Replace "abc" with "XciGdDmDTd5a9oArnATg3d3W1OZiJD7X"

Linux

echo -n "x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "XciGdDmDTd5a9oArnATg3d3W1OZiJD7X" | openssl base64

Windows

set /p="x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac XciGdDmDTd5a9oArnATg3d3W1OZiJD7X" dummy <nul | openssl base64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this doesn't appear to be programming at all, and may well be closed, as topicality has gotten pretty strict in the last year or two.

Second, you aren't creating any kind of signature here. You are simply base64-encoding a string, and that string is different on the two systems because on Windows you are using the `echo` command of the command processor `cmd` which is derived from MSDOS and noticeably different from the `echo` command usually provided by Unix shells (although it *can* vary). Specifically your Linux value is the base64 encoding of the characters

```
x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac abc
```

which are output by the command of the form `echo -n "stuff" more stuff` to most (but not all) Unix shells,
while your Windows value is the base64 encoding of the characters

```
-n "x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT" openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "abc"
```

followed by space, carriage return, and line feed. Note the added dash-n-and-space and quotemarks (both treated as data; CMD `echo` does not take options in the form `-n` nor treat quotes the way a Unix shell does, or even a ported Unix-style program) as well as the trailing space (a difference between the way CMD runs commands on Windows versus the way a shell does on Unix) and CRLF.

If you are on Windows 10, you can install the 'Windows Subsystem for Linux' (WSL) with any common Linux distribution, and use that basically the same way you do any real Unix.

To do this in CMD you need to cheat like this:

```
c:\temp>set /p="x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac abc" dummy <nul | openssl base64
eC1kYXRlOiBXZWQsIDEzIE9jdCAyMDIxIDA5OjMwOjAwIEdNVCBvcGVuc3NsIGRn
c3QgLWJpbmFyeSAtc2hhMjU2IC1obWFjIGFiYw==
```

There may well be a better way in powershell, which corrects many of the minor flaws and silly things in CMD, but I haven't learned enough about it yet to say.

But I don't see why you'd want to; this value is basically useless. What you probably want (or were told) to do is compute the SHA256-HMAC of the date value with a given key. To do that on Unix (or WSL) you need to change your command to

```
echo -n "x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "abc" | openssl base64
*****NOTICE PIPE CHARACTER ADDED HERE ----------^
```

but again for CMD you need to cheat.

Comment: It is weird when I replace the "abc" with "XciGdDmDTd5a9oArnATg3d3W1OZiJD7X", the result would become different again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I install WSL and execute this in command line:

```
wsl echo -n "x-date: Wed, 13 Oct 2021 09:30:00 GMT" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -hmac "XciGdDmDTd5a9oArnATg3d3W1OZiJD7X" | openssl base64
```

It works.